# LibGDX won't upload libraries and create project (Windows 8)

Tags: android, libgdx

I have the next issue. Searched in the web but have not found if someone else has the same problem. 
I've downloaded stable release version of LibGDX from official website.

For some reasons when I launch it and click to create project it shows me only one choice to download LibGDX library (in the required row). It does not offer me to download any of Third-party libraries like "Physics Body Editor loader" or "Universal Tween Engine". And even if I click to download stable or nightly version of LibGDX library, program does not manage that. (Image applied on the link below)! 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/144mnevk8rh883p/Untitled.png

Probably I am following this guide on how to create android game. http://www.kilobolt.com/day-2-setting-up-libgdx.html And there is no such an issue as I have. I was working previously on projects using Intellij Idea and Eclipse for Android. So I certainly have installed SDK manager and JDK on my computer. I have no idea why LibGDX won't update libraries and even won't allow me to create project.

I will very appreciate for your help! Thank you!

Comment: "LibGDX won't upload libraries"... Do you mean "update" instead of "upload"? I don't know why the setup gui does behave like this in windows 8, but you can actually just download a libgdx version yourself and select that in the tool. Then your creation button should be active and you can create the projects.

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX requires to change Name, Package, Game Class and Destination of your Projects first. After completing these steps, all libraries will be downloaded like a charm.

Another thing is that for the first time Third-Party libraries may not appear (for example Tween Engine). But for the second project they appeared for me.

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 2hrs with same issue.
This works finally:

- Copy gdx-setup-ui.jar to any drive/folder (I placed it in D: drive)
- Open command prompt (Start -> search: cmd)
- type D: after C:\Users\xyz>   ...enter
- D:>gdx-setup-ui.jar        ....enter
- Now enter your name,package name... rest details
- Then download libGDX, Universal Engine, Physics Body Editor loader.
- Open Generation Screen -> Launch
- DONE